# How to add One modelAndView object to another ModelAndView object

Tags: object, spring-mvc, addition, model-view

How to add one modelAndView object to another ModelAndView object. Like i have one ModelAndView object mv1 and i want another modelandview object mv2 value to be added to mv1.can i use `mv1.addObject("mv1",mv2);`

Comment: have you tried with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if you want to add one `ModelAndView` inside another:

```
mv1.addObject("mv2", mv2);
```

If you want to include **all objects** from one `ModelAndView` to another one:

```
mv1.addAllObjects(mv2.getModel());
```